# Numpy array of indexes to array of elements

Tags: python, numpy

I have a MxN numpy array containing ints, representing indexes of a big array of size K
How do I convert efficiently my M*N array of indexes to an MxN array of elements?

Example :

```
K = ['a','b','c','d']
M = [[0,3],[2,1]]
```

Result :

```
[['a','d'],['c','b']]
```

Thank you!

Comment: ........ `K[M]`?

Comment: Welp, now I feel dumb. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can make numpy arrays from these lists:

```
import numpy as np

k = np.array(K)
m = np.array(M)
```

and then perform a mapping with `k[m]`:

```
>>> k[m]
array([['a', 'd'],
       ['c', 'b']], dtype='<U1')
```

Here for every element in `m`, we thus "replace" it with the element stored in `k` at the index of the original value of `m` at that location.